# Fold special comments

Tags: folding

I want to fold all special documentation comments, and only all special documentation comments.
To do that I created a new syntax, `doxygenComment` and added highlighting (in red, just to test it).
The comments are getting highlighted correctly, but my `GetCppFold` doesn't seem to work, since no comments are getting folded:

```
augroup filetype_cpp
    autocmd!

    " Create custom doxygen comment style
    autocmd FileType cpp syn region doxygenComment start="/\*\!" end="\*/"
    autocmd FileType cpp hi link doxygenComment cError

    " Fold comments.
    autocmd FileType cpp setlocal foldmethod=expr
    autocmd FileType cpp setlocal foldexpr=GetCppFold(v:lnum)

    " Close all folds.
    autocmd BufRead *.cxx,*.hxx,*.cpp,*.hpp normal zM
augroup END
```

The following function simply checks whether the line is considered a `doxygenComment` or not, and returns the appropriate fold level. Keep in mind, I don't want any additional indent/syntax folding. I only want the comments folded (technically, I would want to have the functions folded, too, but this seems to be quite hard, since the syntax can't decipher between function and namespace or classes).

```
function! GetCppFold(lnum)
    let line = getline(a:lnum)

    " Check whether the line is empty or whitespace only.
    if line =~? '\v^\s*$'
        return '-1'
    endif

    let a:data = join(map(synstack(a:lnum, 1), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")'))
    if a:data =~? ".*omment.*"
        echo "match"
        return '='
    endif

    return '-1'
endfunction
```

Comment: I don't think there's a local foldlevel but try `set foldlevel=2` or similar in the augoup.

Comment: Sorry on my previous comment which I can't edit set foldlevel=0, perhaps, outside this function and only set to 2 for this augroup. You'd need to do it on a BufRead etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're only returning two different values from your function:

- `-1`: the fold level is undefined, use the fold level of a line before or after this line, whichever is the lowest.
- `=`: use fold level from the previous line

If you want the function to work, you're going to need to return an actual fold level at some point.

(Also, you're returning `-1` as a string—I think it should be a number.)

Answer (score 0):

```
autocmd FileType cpp syntax region doxygenComment start="/\*\!" end="\*/" fold
autocmd FileType cpp syntax sync fromstart
autocmd FileType cpp setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

See `:help syn-fold`.

You may be able to use `syntax sync ccomment doxygenComment`.